# Make Emacs Line-Oriented

Tags: terminal-emacs, batch-mode

I heard that *Vim* has an `ex mode` which is **line-oriented**.  
That means users can use the editor by `echo`ing commands to it, e.g.,

```bash
bash$ echo "123" > 123.txt  # 123.txt: 123
bash$ echo "s/2/0
> w" | vim -e 123.txt       # replace "2" with "0", then save the edit
bash$ cat 123.txt           # 123.txt: 103
103
```

---

Is it possible for Emacs to do this?  
If yes, how?

Or, more generally, 
has Emacs implemented the line-oriented feature?  
If not, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`emacs -batch` can do that:

```bash
echo '(progn (find-file "123.txt") (replace-string "2" "0") (save-buffer))' | emacs -batch --eval "(call-interactively #'eval-expression)"
```

This starts emacs in [`batch`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html) mode where it evaluates its command-line arguments and exits. In this case, the only command line argument is `--eval` which is asked to call `eval-expression` interactively. Normally `eval-expression` reads from the minibuffer, but in `batch` mode there is no minibuffer and `eval-expression` reads from `stdin`. The pipe has arranged for Emacs's `stdin` to be connected with the `stdout` of `echo`, so `eval-expression` ends up being called with the `echo` output as its argument. It proceeds to open the file, replace the string and save the buffer. Emacs then exits.

Equivalently but a bit closer in spirit to your example:

```bash
echo '(progn (replace-string "2" "0") (save-buffer))' | emacs -batch --file 123.txt --eval "(call-interactively #'eval-expression)"
```

Here Emacs gets two arguments, a `--file` argument that visits the file and an `--eval` argument as before.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `emacs -batch -eval "(call-interactively #'eval-expression)"` is still a little different from *Vim*'s `ex mode` which is a read and execute **loop**.  I also posted an answer based on yours :-)

Comment: You are right, although I suspect nobody will want to do it this way: `vim`'s command "language" is simple enough to be able to type it in,  but even in that case, a purpose-made filter can be much more convenient (e.g. `sed` or `awk`). OTOH, Emacs is heavily weighted towards interactive use, so the command language is elisp: very flexible and powerful for writing extensions and scripting it but a bit too verbose to use interactively on the command line, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

According to [@NickD](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/14825/)’s answer, 
to make Emacs **line-oriented** just like *Vim*’s `ex mode`, use:

```bash
$ emacs -batch \
>       -eval "(while t \
>                (write-char ?\\n) \
>                (call-interactively #'eval-expression))"
```

This will provide you with a read and execute **loop**.